# Cannot find symbol error bufferedreader

Tags: java

THIS IS MY CODE

```
 import java.IO.*; 
 class jed { 
    public static void main (String args[]){

    BufferedReader datain = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String name =" ";
    System.out.print("What is your name?:"); 
    try{ 
       name = datain.readline(); 
    } catch(IOException e) { 
      System.out.print("Error");
    } 

    System.out.print("Your name is" + name); } }
```

THIS IS THE ERROR

```
 D:\>javac jed.java jed.java:1: error: package java.IO does not exist
 import java.IO.*; ^ jed.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
 BufferedReader datain = new BufferedReader(new
 InputStreamReader(System.in)); ^   symbol:   class BufferedReader  
 location: class jed jed.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
 BufferedReader datain = new BufferedReader(new
 InputStreamReader(System.in)); ^   symbol:   class BufferedReader   
 location: class jed jed.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
 BufferedReader datain = new BufferedReader(new
 InputStreamReader(System.in));^   symbol:   class InputStreamReader   
 location: class jed jed.java:10: error: cannot
 find symbol catch(IOException e){^   symbol:  class IOException                                                      location: class jed 5 errors
```

I will appreciate any help I can get to fix this issue. Thank you

Comment: It pretty much says it in the error... java.IO does not exist.

Comment: change it to `import java.io.*;`. voting to close as caused-by-typographical-error.

Comment: Here's a hint... Java is case-sensitive.

Comment: @NathanHughes Is that really a reason to close?

Comment: @JamesB: yes, read the close dialog: "This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting. " I think it fits, it doesn't seem like something that would help others.

Comment: I stand corrected, fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

Java is case sensitive. You should import `java.io.*`, instead of `java.IO.*`.

Answer (score 3):

Java is case sensitive.

Your import is wrong. Change

```
import java.IO.*;
```

to

```
import java.io.*;
```

In defence of the compiler it does actually tell you the problem clearly:

> error: package java.IO does not exist import java.IO.*;

Comment: Whoever marked up my answer should really do the same for Vash - Damian Leszczyński

Answer (score 0):

You have to change `.readline()`
to `.readLine()`, because java is case sensitive.